# How can I push my local repository to remote repository?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, git, github, push

This is my first time using Git on Visual Studio 2010.

First of all, I create an account on GitHub with the username `sonergonul` and created a blank repository called [deneme](https://github.com/sonergonul/deneme).

After that, I installed [Git](http://git-scm.com/), [Git Source Control provider](http://gitscc.codeplex.com/) and [Git extensions](http://code.google.com/p/gitextensions/). I created a sample project called `ProgramConsole`. When I look at Visual Studio, it looks like this:

[image]

On the Git Pending Changes dialog, I can commit changes. When I look at Git extension program, it looks ok and it sees the last commit.

[image]

When I commit with Git extension program, this doesn't push the local respository to Github. When I look at `Visual Studio->Git->Manage Remotes`, there is an option called remote repositeries.

I tried all possibilities on this option, but I couldn't find right settings.

[image]

Also when I push this repo, it takes more than an hour (still on process).

[image]

Am I missing something here? If anyone can explain with this process step by step, I will be 
greatful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As illustrated in this [Youtube video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JByfXdbVAiE&t=0m45s), the push should not last more than a few seconds ;)

In Git Extensions, you need to select Plugins->GitHub, and enter your Github login and password, if you want to push using an https address.

Comment: Note: that credential issue was fixed in recent "GitExtension" release: https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions/issues/898